# How add annotation to semilogx in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, annotations

I would like to add desciption on the curves in Matlab using annotation, but I always see the below error

```
Error using annotation
Unknown argument.

Error in del (line 5)
annotation('textarrow',Q,y,'String','y = x ')
```

May I get some assistance, please? Doesn't annotation work with semilogx?

```
Q = [16,32,64,128,256,512,1024];
y = [9     9     9     9     5     0     0]*0.25;
y1 = [45    37    25    21     5     0     0]*0.25;
semilogx(Q,y,Q,y1)
annotation('textarrow',Q,y,'String','\theta =0 ')
annotation('textarrow',Q,y1,'String','\theta = 10 ')
xlabel('Q oder');
ylabel('Coverage area m^2');
grid on;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`annotation` creates a line between two points.

The input to `annotation` must be on the format

```
x = [0.3 0.5];
y = [0.6 0.5];
annotation('textarrow',x,y,'String','\theta =0 ')
```

where `x` and `y` are selected by you. This is typically a bit of trial and error to make it look nice.

Comment: Why did you put two values to x and two values to y?

Comment: They are the coordinates the arrow will go from and to. From `(0.3, 0.6)` to `(0.5, 0.5)`.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks a lot again.